# Create a list that counts from the beginning to the current value

Tags: r

I currently have a data table that looks like so:

```
Name     Person     Date
A        1          1/1/2004
A        2          1/3/2004
A        3          1/9/2004 
B        4          1/7/2004
B        5          1/10/2004 
B        6          1/17/2004
```

I am trying to create a new data table that looks like:

```
Name     Person     Date
A        1          1/1/2004
A        2          1/1/2004
A        2          1/3/2004
A        3          1/1/2004
A        3          1/3/2004
A        3          1/9/2004
B        4          1/7/2004
B        5          1/7/2004
B        5          1/10/2004
B        6          1/7/2004
B        6          1/10/2004
B        6          1/17/2004
```

where the date starts from the minimum date of the name group.

So far, I have done something like this:

```
data$D = ave(data$Date, data$Name, FUN=min)
diff =  data$Date - data$D
sequence(diff) + rep(data$D,diff)
```

However, this only yields a repetition that also counts the dates in between. Is there an easy way to do expand out from the minimum date? Thank you!

Comment: Is your data set is in `data.table` format or by "data table" you just mean a `data.frame`?

Comment: It is in data.table format, but i can also do it in data.frame. Thanks!

Comment: @AlbertLu. Sorry, I thought you were working with data.frame from the codes you used.

Comment: @akrun I can easily convert to data.frame as well. It is not an issue, thanks!

Comment: @akrun, btw, `dplyr` works great with `data.table` objects, so your second solution should be fine either way

Comment: @David Arenburg and Albert Liu thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a `data.table` solution, so here goes

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, list(Person = rep(Person, seq_len(.N)),
                   Date = Date[sequence(seq_len(.N))]), by = Name]

#     Name Person      Date
#  1:    A      1  1/1/2004
#  2:    A      2  1/1/2004
#  3:    A      2  1/3/2004
#  4:    A      3  1/1/2004
#  5:    A      3  1/3/2004
#  6:    A      3  1/9/2004
#  7:    B      4  1/7/2004
#  8:    B      5  1/7/2004
#  9:    B      5 1/10/2004
# 10:    B      6  1/7/2004
# 11:    B      6 1/10/2004
# 12:    B      6 1/17/2004
```

---

**Edit**

This is the data set that was used for this answer

```
data <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
        "B"), class = "factor"), Person = 1:6, Date = structure(c(1L, 
        4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1/1/2004", "1/10/2004", "1/17/2004", 
        "1/3/2004", "1/7/2004", "1/9/2004"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
         "Person", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
         ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, when I try running the code, it says something about 'unexpected "=" '. Is this a data.table thing? Thanks!

Comment: There is no error when I'm running it. See my edit, I've posted the data set I've used

Comment: Am I missing something or "A 2" and "B 5" do not seem to match wanted output?

Answer (score 3):

If `dat` is the dataset

```
res <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(dat, dat$Name),
     function(x) {
     Date1 <- as.Date(x$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
     x <- x[order(Date1),]
     indx <- seq_len(nrow(x))
     cbind(x[rep(indx,indx), 1:2], Date=x[sequence(indx),3])}))

 row.names(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
 res
#  Name Person     Date
#1     A      1    1/1/2004
#2     A      2    1/1/2004
#3     A      2    1/3/2004
#4     A      3    1/1/2004
#5     A      3    1/3/2004
#6     A      3    1/9/2004
#7     B      4    1/7/2004
#8     B      5    1/7/2004
#9     B      5   1/10/2004
#10    B      6    1/7/2004
#11    B      6   1/10/2004
#12    B      6   1/17/2004
```

Using `dplyr`

```
dat %>% 
group_by(Name) %>%
mutate(Date1= as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
arrange(Name, Date1) %>% 
mutate(N= row_number()) %>% 
do(data.frame(.[rep(.$N, .$N),1:2], Date=.[sequence(.$N),3],stringsAsFactors=F))

#   Name Person      Date
#1     A      1  1/1/2004
#2     A      2  1/1/2004
#3     A      2  1/3/2004
#4     A      3  1/1/2004
#5     A      3  1/3/2004
#6     A      3  1/9/2004
#7     B      4  1/7/2004
#8     B      5  1/7/2004
#9     B      5 1/10/2004
#10    B      6  1/7/2004
#11    B      6 1/10/2004
#12    B      6 1/17/2004
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested `lapply`:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="Name     Person     Date
A        1          1/1/2004
A        2          1/3/2004
A        3          1/9/2004 
B        4          1/7/2004
B        5          1/10/2004 
B        6          1/17/2004",header=TRUE)

#convert to date, to be used for min()
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")

#result
res <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(split(df,df$Name),
                 function(i){
                   do.call(rbind,
                           lapply(unique(i$Person),
                                  function(j){
                                    d <- i[ i$Date<=min(i[ i$Person==j,"Date"]),]
                                    d$Person <- j
                                    return(d)}))
                 })
  )

# Name Person       Date
# A.1     A      1 2004-01-01
# A.2     A      2 2004-01-01
# A.3     A      2 2004-01-03
# A.4     A      3 2004-01-01
# A.5     A      3 2004-01-03
# A.6     A      3 2004-01-09
# B.4     B      4 2004-01-07
# B.41    B      5 2004-01-07
# B.5     B      5 2004-01-10
# B.42    B      6 2004-01-07
# B.51    B      6 2004-01-10
# B.6     B      6 2004-01-17
```